# Ordenar resultado usando CASE e BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql

No primeiro código logo abaixo, consigo listar certinho o preço do frete da tabela transportes via a faixa de `cep` e `peso`, porem estou tendo um problema, preciso ordenar o resultado de acordo como cep enviado, dependendo da consulta esta caindo na segunda linha e preciso que fique na primeira, não estou sabendo usar a função  `CASE` junto com `BETWEEN` para odernar para primieira posição depois na cláusula `ORDER BY`

**Desta forma funciona certinho, sem o `CASE`**

```
SELECT

`Transportadora`.*,

FROM `envio_transportadora` AS `Transportadora` 
    INNER JOIN `shop_envio` AS `ShopEnvio` 
ON (`ShopEnvio`.`id_envio` = `Transportadora`.`id_envio_default` AND `ShopEnvio`.`ativo` = 'True' AND `ShopEnvio`.`id_shop_default` = '5')  
    WHERE 
'78000-000' BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`cep_inicio` AND `Transportadora`.`cep_fim` AND 13 BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`peso_inicial` AND `Transportadora`.`peso_final`
```

**Já com o `CASE` da erro de syntax na `query`** segue abaixo:

```
SELECT

`Transportadora`.*,

((CASE WHEN '78000-000' BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`cep_inicio` AND `Transportadora`.`cep_fim`)) AS cep_ordenar 

FROM `envio_transportadora` AS `Transportadora` 
    INNER JOIN `shop_envio` AS `ShopEnvio` 
ON (`ShopEnvio`.`id_envio` = `Transportadora`.`id_envio_default` AND `ShopEnvio`.`ativo` = 'True' AND `ShopEnvio`.`id_shop_default` = '5')  
    WHERE 
'78000-000' BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`cep_inicio` AND `Transportadora`.`cep_fim` AND 13 BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`peso_inicial` AND `Transportadora`.`peso_final`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está fazendo o uso do CASE de forma errada, o correto seria algo como isso:

```
CASE condicao
 WHEN valor1 THEN 'valor1'
 WHEN valor2 THEN 'valor2'
 ELSE 'valor_alternativo'
END
```

E mesmo assim, não há necessidade de usar isso para ordenar dados, além disso, no mysql existe outras formas de fazer uso de condições como o uso do IF, IFNULL, etc. Exemplo:

```
 IF('condicao', valor_if_dondicao, 'valor_else_condicao') AS saida
```

Para ordenar não precisa de nada disso, basta usar ORDER BY no final das sua query e colocar a lista de preferência da ordem, exemplo:

```
ORDER BY `Transportadora`.`cep_inicio` ASC, `Transportadora`.`cep_fim` ASC
```

Ou ainda fazer um order by mais personalizado pelo campo:

```
ORDER BY FIELD (`Transportadora`.`cep_inicio`,'78000-000','79000-000','...') ASC,
         FIELD (`Transportadora`.`cep_fim`,'...','...') ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você não sabe utilizar o CASE. Com o case podemos comprar um determinado valor e ter um resultado de acordo com este valor. Por exemplo:

```
CASE numero
  WHEN 1 THEN 'um'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'dois'
  ELSE 'outro'
END
```

Assim podemos compara uma coluna, que no caso foi número, a diversos valores e dependendo do valor retornar um outro valor específico. Fora que não vi nenhuma cláusula ORDER BY.

Acesse o meu blog https://oraclepress.wordpress.com que tem várias coisas de SQL

Comment: Saber que estou usando CASE de forma incorreta, isso eu sei, até porque, antes de perguntar pesquisei muito, [aqui tem um exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593355/using-between-in-case-sql-statement) com CASE e BETWEEN, só achei que daria para adaptar ao meu problema, e para quem entende de SQL, order by é o de menos no exemplo. Agora postar um blog pessoal que fala sobre oracle não resolve.

Comment: Me desculpe se eu o ofendi, só quero ajudar mesmo. Poderia explicar como você gostaria de utilizar o CASE com o BETWEEN e o ORDER BY? Ficarei grato em poder te ajudar. Só não entendi muito bem o que você queria.

Comment: Que bom que sabe, porque para CASE, o correto seria  usar o between com WHEN 'cep_ordenar' e não AS 'cep_ordenar'.  :D

Comment: Seria algo como: CASE WHEN
      '78000-000' BETWEEN `Transportadora`.`cep_inicio` AND `Transportadora`.`cep_fim` THEN '78000-000' 
 ELSE NULL 
 END AS cep_ordenar